# General Design Requirements to make an application "pluggable"

Tags: design-patterns, plugins

I am wondering if there are programming language agnostic paradigms, models, patterns, etc for designing an application for which the author intends to allow third party developers to write plugins.

For example, if you wanted to create some type of text editor, you want to just focus on the main components and let someone else then add a loadable plugin which does spell checking, grammar, word count, reading level, etc... In the basic editor the original author creates, what type of things do they need to do to manage entry points, hooks, etc.

Are there any techniques or methods to manage this, or does this really depend on platform, languages, etc. (e.g., same concepts used for plugins in web app versus desktop GUI apps? - C++ vs Python)

Answer (score 0):

This is a multilevel and very generic question. Relating to the fundamental OO design concepts the Dependency Inversion (plus the related Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection) SOLID principle might help you. Low Coupling, Indirection and Polymorphism from GRASP will give some guidance as well.

Each specific enterprise-adopted platform almost always provides concrete mechanics for creating the pluggable architecture.

Most famous is probably Java’s OSGi that has been ported to several other platforms.
Being in .NET world you might investigate MEF/MAF frameworks or the types from System.AddIn namespace.

In addition you might look into the usage of any DI container that is something less abstract than just following the OO design principles and more generic than using OSGi or MEF/MAF. An example would be Unity from Microsoft.

Additionally depending on the size of your system you might want to consider the event-driven integration that usually provides clear and concise contracts and very loose coupling. RabbitMQ tutorial provides the basic patterns but actually you may end up using something more low-level (ZMQ) or high-level (BizTalk, Tibco etc).